# How create a scrollable TabLayout from google's guideline for Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

How I can create a scrollable `TabLayout` with margin for 1st tab, but when user scrolls tabs, they would be scrolled along the entire width?

`layout_marginStart` doesn't work in this case.

[Example from Google (gif)](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsY1JuWnJGSHpiQkE/components-tabs-typesoftabs_scrollable_tabs_01_xhdpi_003.webm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! Just use

```
app:tabContentStart="72dp"
```